Assistance Required for OpenSSL 3.3.2 Upgrade in Yocto
We are in the process of upgrading OpenSSL from version 1.0.2 to 3.3.2 in our Yocto (Pyro) environment. During the build, we encountered an issue related to the configuration step. The specific error log is as follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
| Can't open perl script "perlpath.pl": No such file or directory
| WARNING: exit code 2 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_configure

It appears that the perlpath.pl script is missing, and we have not been able to identify a patch or solution to address this. How to resolve this issue?
I am expecting how to upgrade openssl 1.0.2 to 3.3.2 version is there is any patch file available for   3.3.2 libssl version Y because I have patches for 1.0.2 version, If found patches it would be helpful or any idea how to solve this?
